# ion-nav-back-button and state.go - back action working ambigously

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic along with AngularJS (stateProvider)

I have added following code in a default template for abstract state

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
 <ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

When the default controller is loaded (Displays StateA), it transitions to another state (StateB) by invoking

```
$state.go(...);
```

This results in loading another template and it gets displayed in child view. Additionally, it also activates back button.

1. After clicking the back button in nav bar, it takes back to the default page (StateA).
2. The back button in navbar becomes invisible, but if I press back button on mobile, it takes me back to the transitioned state (StateB).

This is bit weird, as why the StateB is again getting displayed instead of application getting closed.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

> As a user navigates throughout your app, Ionic is able to keep track of their navigation history. By knowing their history, transitions between views correctly enter and exit using the platform's transition style.
>
> From [Ionic Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Ionic will automatically keep track of your state history for you using stateProvider, so it is like a stack of history.

You start from state A, the stack has only one page: A.

```
| A |
```

After that you go to state B, it will be push into the history stack:

```
| B |
| A |
```

And the nav-view provided by Ionic will show a back button in the nav-bar because it thought you are doing a state transition and helped you to keep the history for you (like the navigation controller in iOS).

Then if you click the back button in nav-bar, the history stack pop out the B, and display A for you again.

```
| A |
```

The back button will be removed for you because you go back to the initial state(like a root page).

> why click back button on mobile, it takes me back to the
>   transitioned state?

You are manipulate the window history of the global window object(Compiled Ionic App is still consider a web app, even in mobile platform I think). This is pretty much like what you do when you hit the Back button in your browser.

```
/A <- /B(window history) <- /A (current page)
```

1. If you want to do something with ionicHistory, check [this discussion](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-clear-out-the-nav-router-history-and-prevent-a-back-button/356/6)
2. If you want to do something with your device button behavior, check [this related topics](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-the-hardware-back-buttons/1505/29)

I am also learning the Ionic here, so not sure am I get all concepts correct or not. Hope this helps!

Comment: I pretty much understand how history works, the problem is once the "back" button is clicked on navbar, state B should be removed from history and now pressing Back on device while on state A, should not result displaying stateB. But unfortunately state B is getting displayed.

Comment: @CuriousMind I think the "back" button on device will go back to previous page using the window.history.back(). The window.history is different the $ionicHistory one, and I am not sure if you can modify it or not. Maybe you want to change your "back" button's behavior to achieve what you want.

Comment: @CuriousMind I agree that should be the case. Device back button and Ionic's back button should do similar things. I think Ionic's backstack handling is very buggy from that perspective.